# Livy REST API: GET requests work but POST requests fail with '401 Authentication required'

Tags: kerberos, spring-rest, livy

I’ve written a Java client for parts of Livy’s REST API at https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/docs/rest-api.md. The client uses Spring’s `RestTemplate.getForObject()` and `postForObject()` to make GET and POST requests respectively. The Livy server is secured with Kerberos.

[`GET /sessions`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/docs/rest-api.md#get-sessions) and [`GET /batches`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/docs/rest-api.md#get-batches) requests work fine: I get the expected responses from Livy. But both [`POST /sessions`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/docs/rest-api.md#post-sessions) and [`POST /batches`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/docs/rest-api.md#post-batches) requests fail with:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Authentication required
```

Does anyone know why the POST requests fail when the GET requests succeed? My code does nothing explicit with authentication.

I've tried authenticating as several different users via Kerberos but I always get this problem. Does Livy need extra configuration to allow POST requests from particular users (since POST requests effectively create interactive sessions or submit jobs to Spark)?

Comment: Did you trace the HTTP headers sent/received during the SPNego "negotiation" (that always starts with a `401` challenge but should end either with `200` or `403`)? Any visible difference in the sequence of events for _GET_ and _POST_  e.g. a redirection at some point?

Comment: There was a similar issue with WebHDFS, long ago, but because of a bug in Java 6 `net`library... hopefully you are using something more recent!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! No, I'm using Java 8 (and Livy v0.3.0 BTW). I haven't managed to trace those HTTP headers but it looks like Livy requires extra security for POST requests compared to GET requests. Currently trying with a special version of Spring's `RestTemplate` to use with Kerberos: [`KerberosRestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/current/reference/html/ssk-resttemplate.html). Will post more when I get another chance in a few days...

Comment: For debugging purposes you may try a `curl` command-line HTTP query (if the Kerberos TGT is available in the default cache) with `curl --negotiate -u : --trace-ascii - <some-GET-URL>` then `-X POST --data 'blah blah' <some-POST-URL>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that whilst the regular [`org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) class is sufficient for GET requests, you need to use [`org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/kerberos/client/KerberosRestTemplate.html) for POST requests. You may also need to add an extra header to POST requests if the Livy server has CSRF (cross-site request forgery) protection enabled as described [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/branch-0.3/conf/livy.conf#L50-L52).

**GET /batches example**

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
GetBatchesResponse response2 = restTemplate.getForObject("http://your_livy_server:8998" + "/batches", GetBatchesResponse.class);
```

where `GetBatchesResponse` is a simple POJO I've written that represents the [response body](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/docs/rest-api.md#response-body-9) to `GET /batches`.

**POST /batches example**

```
PostBatchesRequest postRequestBody = new PostBatchesRequest();
postRequestBody.setFile("/path/to/your/application"); // In HDFS

KerberosRestTemplate kerberosRestTemplate = new KerberosRestTemplate("path_to_your_key_tab_file", "your_user@your_realm");

// Add CSRF header if required:
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("X-Requested-By", "your_user@your_realm");
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity<PostBatchesRequest> postRequest = new HttpEntity<PostBatchesRequest>(postRequestBody, headers);

Batch batch = kerberosRestTemplate.postForObject("http://your_livy_server:8998" + "/batches", postRequest, Batch.class);
```

where `PostBatchesRequest` and `Batch` are POJOs I've written to represent the [request body](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/docs/rest-api.md#request-body-3) and [response](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/docs/rest-api.md#response-body-10) respectively.

Comment: Credit is due to Hortonworks for helping me arrive at this solution!

Comment: If possible can you paste the imports and dependencies too? I am having trouble to find them. I am also trying to post a request to Livy.

Comment: @Explorer - You can't find the POJOs (such as `PostBatchesRequest`) because I wrote them. They're company code so I can't share them but all I did was write a Java client for Livy's REST API and used `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` to make GET requests or `org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplate` to make POST requests..